How to extract a list of records with certain criteria met in one table while identifiers extracted from another table?
In Microsoft Excel, I have a table named TableTwo, with fields:

tName
dDate
tStatus

tName is key-identifier of the records.
We extract a list of tName, named tNames, from table TableOne. Then for each tName in tNames, we want to find records from TableTwo that its dDate is the maximum value of corresponding records with this tName, and their tStatus is not Accepted.
TableOne



tName
Category
startDate




asset1
cat1



asset2
cat1



asset3
cat1



asset4
cat2



asset5
cat3




TableTwo



tName
dDate
tStaus




asset1
14010201
Accepted


asset1
13990304
Accepted


asset2
14010420
Accepted


asset3
14020512
Accepted


asset1
14030305
Rejected


asset1
14030306
Accepted


asset1
14030307
Postponed


asset2
14030307
Rejected


asset3
14030307
Accepted


asset4
14030307
Accepted


asset4
14030308
Rejected


asset5
14030309
Accepted


asset2
14030310
Accepted


asset2
14030311
Rejected



Final Results:



tName
dDate
tStatus




asset1
14030307
Postponed


asset2
14030311
Rejected



I've tried to use LET and Filter function, first finding tNames, then inspecting TableTwo to find records that met criterias.

Attempt 1 — Output: #N/A
=LET(
    tNames, FILTER(TableOne[tName],(TableOne[Category]="cat1"),"NoAsset"),
    dDates, TableTwo[dDate],
    tStatuses, TableTwo[tStatus],
    maxDates, MAXIFS(TableTwo[dDate], TableTwo[tName], tNames),
    result, IF((TableTwo[dDate]=maxDates)*(TableTwo[tStatus]<>"Accepted"), TableTwo[tName], ""),
    FILTER(result, result<>"")
)

Attempt 2 — Output: #Value!
=LET(tNames,FILTER(TableOne[tName],(TableOne[Category]="cat1"),"NoAsset"),
cntr, SEQUENCE(ROWS(tNames)),
rngTwo,FILTER(tNames,(TableTwo[tName]=INDEX(tNames,cntr))*(TableTwo[dDate]=MAXIFS(TableTwo[dDate],TableTwo[tName],INDEX(tNames,cntr)))*(TableTwo[tStatus]<>"Accepted")),
r,SEQUENCE(ROWS(rngTwo)),
output,INDEX(rngTwo,r),
output)


To get the desired output, here is what you should do, refer the following formula:


=LET(
     a, FILTER(TableOne[tName],TableOne[Category]="cat1","NoAsset"),
     b, MAXIFS(TableTwo[dDate],TableTwo[tName],a),
     c, (1-ISNA(XMATCH(TableTwo[dDate]&TableTwo[tName],b&a))),
     FILTER(TableTwo,c*(TableTwo[tStaus]<>"Accepted")))


In place of 1-ISNA( one can also use ISNUMBER(

You can also use MMULT() function:
=LET(
     a, FILTER(TableOne[tName],TableOne[Category]="cat1","NoAsset"),
     b, MAXIFS(TableTwo[dDate],TableTwo[tName],a),
     c, MMULT((TableTwo[tName]=TRANSPOSE(a))*
              (TableTwo[dDate]=TRANSPOSE(b))*
              (TableTwo[tStaus]<>"Accepted"),
        {1;1;1}),
     FILTER(TableTwo,c))



I think you can sort TableTwo first and then use "search from first to last" option of XMATCH to display the results:
Updated, since you have only Excel 2021, so you will stick to INDEX and FILTER. (cannot use CHOOSEROWS, TOCOL etc).
=LET(
    tNames, FILTER(TableOne[tName], (TableOne[Category] = "cat1"), "NoAsset"),
    sorted, SORT(FILTER(TableTwo, TableTwo[tStaus] <> "Accepted", ""), 2, -1),
    row_nums, XMATCH(tNames, INDEX(sorted, , 1), 0, 1),
    filtered_row_nums, FILTER(row_nums, ISNUMBER(row_nums), ""),
    INDEX(sorted, filtered_row_nums, {1, 2, 3})
)


